# How to make sound off/on switch or button C# portable class project using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

```
public SettingsPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    lblResult.Text = $"Great! you got {MainPage.count} out of {App.CurrentGame.NumberOfQuestions}" +
        $" questions correct";
    lblPResult.Text = $"Total Points: {MainPage.points}";

    btnSound.Clicked += BtnSound_Clicked;


}

private void BtnSound_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Here is the SettingsPage.xaml.cs code behind that im trying to code a button. that will either be pressed for the sound to be toggled on or off. i was using a switch before however, every time i clicked my settings button on my main page to navigate to the setting page the toggle switch would return the same state. i don't know how to fix it. i think a switch would be easier but im kinda new and i'm just trying to learn.

Comment: you need to save the state of the Sounds setting, and then initialize the switch on the settings page to the saved value when the page loads.  None of this happens automatically - you have to write code to do it

Comment: As above comments you need to store the state of sounds setting, for that you can use Settings plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin if you want to store the state even when the app is not running.

Comment: Great thanks guys! i added a bool variable to the main page to correspond to the setting page sound button when toggled. that way it keeps track if the sound is on or off. i will check the plugin @LeslieCorrea because i do want to have the sound stay off if the user closes the app completely.